# What's the priority order of primary, secondary and tertiary amino groups in IUPAC nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, amines

It's a really simple question but I didn't get answer to this anywhere. What's the priority order of primary, secondary and tertiary amino groups in IUPAC nomenclature.

For example what would be the name of the following compound:

[image: compound]

Comment: It's possible to answer the question 'how is this named?', but it doesn't involve comparing between primary, secondary, and tertiary amino groups at all (see e.g. https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P6.html#6202040102), so let's take a step back first. Presumably you have identified the 'parent hydride' or the 'parent chain' as a hexane. Amines are *suffixes* (unless there's another more important group, which isn't the case here), so the name is going to look like (...)hexane-x,y,z-triamine; and the part which you are stuck at is how to number the chain to determine `x,y,z`, is that correct?

Comment: @orthocresol Yes exactly.

Comment: An example that fits better with the title would be a case where you can only choose one of the amino groups as a suffix like 2-{3-(2-aminoethyl)-5-[2-(methylamino)ethyl]phenyl}-N,N-dimethylethan-1-amine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to answer the question 'how is this named?', but it doesn't involve comparing between primary, secondary, and tertiary amino groups at all.

The most relevant part of the IUPAC Blue Book is [P-62.2.4](https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P6.html#620204); even if you don't want to read the fine print, there are a few examples there which might let you see a pattern.

You have identified the parent chain as a hexane. Now, the idea of 'priority' between functional groups is used when deciding which of them becomes the *suffix*. For example, carboxylic acids have quite high priority, so where possible, you want to name acids as ...-oic acid; see [Table 4.4 in P-43](https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P4.html#43). If you scroll down to entry 51 in that table, you'll see that amines are also suffixes, but there isn't a distinction between primary, secondary, and tertiary amines.

In fact, in your compound, *all* of the amines can be suffixes, so you don't need to choose between them. The name is therefore going to be something like `(...)hexane-x,y,z-triamine`, where `(...)` are some substituents, and `x,y,z` are the locants for the three amines. Note that the extra alkyl groups on the nitrogens also become substituents.

How do we choose those values `x,y,z`? Well, there are two options:

[image: hexanetriamines]

The left gives us hexane-1,3,4-triamine, and right gives us hexane-3,4,6-triamine. [P-14.4(e)](https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P1.html#1404) says that the lowest locants should be chosen for the suffixes. Because the locant set `1,3,4` is lower than `3,4,6`, we choose the numbering on the left.*

To finish up, we just need to add in the extra substituents. These are:

1. a methyl group on N attached to C–1
2. an ethyl group on N attached to C–1
3. a methyl group on N attached to C–4

To name these, we use [P-62.2.4](https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P6.html#620204) again:

> The locant of the parent hydride to which the nitrogen atom is attached is cited as a superscript to the letter locant *N*, for example, *N*<sup>2</sup>, *N*<sup>5</sup>, etc..

giving us the full name

***N*<sup>1</sup>-ethyl-*N*<sup>1</sup>,*N*<sup>4</sup>-dimethylhexane-1,3,4-triamine**

(where ethyl comes before dimethyl due to the usual alphabetical ordering).

---

* This means a point-by-point comparison of the two locant sets (see [P-14.3.5](https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/P1.html#140305)). So, you compare the lowest member of `1,3,4` with the lowest member of `3,4,6`, i.e. 1 vs 3; and since 1 is smaller than 3, `1,3,4` is lower than `3,4,6`. Some places still suggest that you should sum up all the locants and compare them, which is not correct at all.